# Include file data in Perl array

Tags: perl

I am trying to pass all the data from a file into a Perl array and then I am trying to use a foreach loop to process every string in the array. The problem is that the foreach instead of printing each individual line is printing the entire array.I am using the following script.

```
while (<FILE>) {
  $_ =~ s/(\)|\()//g;
  push @array, $_;
}

foreach $n(@array) {
  print "$n\n";
}
```

Say for example the data in the array is `@array=qw(He goes to the school everyday)`
the array is getting printed properly but the foreach loop instead of printing every element on different line is printing the entire array.

Comment: I don't see how that loop would produce anything other than `"He\ngoes\nto\nthe\nschool\everyday\n"` given that `@array`. Any chance of getting a whole minimal script along with sample input and output?

Comment: @muistooshort is right.show your input file and the expected output file alongwith the script

Comment: @muistooshort check out the answer provided by me (or TLP), it will print "He\n\ngoes\n\nto\n\n ..." etc.

Comment: @refp: Yes, there will be double newlines from the file (but not from `@array=qw(He goes to the school everyday)`). Am I just confused about what "printing the entire array" means or are the newlines supposed to be there and "printing the entire array" is code for "double newlines"?

Comment: @nandini You know, if you are having problems expressing what you mean, a very simple way to do that is to *show* 1) What you expect, 2) What you actually get.

Comment: @nandini Please do not take my previous comment as an excuse to repeat the `qw(He goes to the school)` example. =) Because that is clearly false. Use your actual input/output.

Comment: If you want to eliminate parenthesis characters, then this is much easier to understand (and faster too): $_ =~ tr/()//d;

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments, I am guessing that your problem is that your source file does not contain any newlines: I.e. the entire file is just one line. Some text editors just wrap the text without actually adding any line break characters.

There is no "solution" to that problem; You have to add line breaks where you want them. You could write a script to do it, but I doubt it would make much sense. It all depends on what you want to do with this text.

Here's my code suggestions for your snippet.

```
chomp(@array = <FILE>);
s/[()]//g for @array;
print "$_\n" for @array;
```

or

```
@array = <FILE>;
s/[()]//g for @array;
print @array;
```

Note that if you have a file from another filesystem, you may get `\r` characters left over at the end of your strings after `chomp`, causing the output to look corrupted, overwriting itself.

Additional notes:

- `(\)|\()` is better written as a character class: `[()]`.
- `@array = <FILE>` will read the entire file into the array. No need
  to loop.
- As shown in my examples, `print` can be assigned a list of items
  (e.g. an array) as arguments. And you can have a postfix loop to
  print sequentially.
- With a (postfix) loop, all the loop elements are aliased to `$_`,
  which is a handy way to do substitutions on the array.

Comment: My data file-------------------------------------------------------In recent years many risk factors for the development of breast cancer that are linked to estrogens have been identified, and roscovitine (ROSC), a selective cyclin-dependent kinase (CDK) inhibitor, has been shown to be an efficient inhibitor of the proliferation of human breast cancer cells. Therefore, we have examined the possibility that interference with estrogen signaling.

Comment: @nandini Have you considered the possibility that your file does not contain any newlines? Some text processors just wrap text without actually adding line breaks.

Comment: So what could be the solution, I have copied the above data from literature

Comment: @nandini: Can you paste the data file into your question in a code block? The "no line breaks" guess sounds pretty good.

Comment: @nandini Solution to what? Do you want your text formatted? I suspect that is something you need to do manually.

Comment: I copy pasted the file in an array instead of calling the file externally and also added new lines. It works for the file that is manually pasted into array but doesn't work if the file is called. I also have added newlines in the file.

Comment: try `cat file.txt` to see exactly what you have in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Since the entire file is just one line.You can split the string on basis of whitespace and print every element of array in new line

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(FILE,'YOURFILE' ) || die ("could not open");
my $line= <FILE>;
my @array = split ' ',$line;
foreach my $n(@array)
{
print "$n\n";
  }
close(FILE);
```

Input File

```
In recent years many risk factors for the development of breast cancer that .....
```

Output

```
In
recent
years
many
risk
factors
for
the
development
of
breast
cancer
that
.....
```

Comment: @nandini If it worked for you then formal way of appreciating in StackOverflow is to accept it as an answer :)